# How to call a rest service in wso2 api manager 1.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am having a login (of some another application) , now i want that same login for wso2 api store and authenticate the user,,

Is it possible to call it using rest service in wso2 api manager for user authentication.?? if yes then how .??

Comment: What do you mean by same login? Single Sign On betwen that app and WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: I meant  when I enter the detail in wso2 login page then it will call a rest api of some other application, based on the response from the rest api I want to either go to home page or show an error message.

Comment: Yes , i need Single Sign On betwen that app and WSO2 API Manager as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Add a new custom user store manager to WSO2 api manager. every user manger has a domain name and you can add one or more user store.
In user store you can call rest api or every other method.
You can use user store like this:

username : domain.com/username

password : password

We use this method to authenticate our user with oauth2.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager